# Slow down connection for Browser for testing

Tags: javascript, apache, google-chrome, web-applications, opera

I am developing a JS+CSS+HTML Webapplication that is deployed on a local Apache. For debudding, I want to simulate a slow connection.

What is the best way to do that? I am not looking for a way to slow down my actual connection, just the loading this page (e.g. a Chrome/Opera Extension or an Apache module)

Comment: Do you want to interact with the site under a slow connection, or just figure out what the load times would be for users of various connection-speeds?

Comment: I always wanted something like that so I could test my code's performance.

Comment: I want to really interact with the website and find out how the site "feels" and all my lazy initialisation works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on a Mac, this might be of interest - it allows you to simulate different network conditions.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac

See the second answer (and give credit for the answer) by Randy6T9

> [Speed Limit](http://mschrag.github.io) is a System Preferences pane for intentionally and selectively slowing down specific ports and domains

Comment: I found this answer and I think this slows down my connection in general. Something I would prefer not to do and I am pretty sure this will not affect my local apache

Comment: @Tobo Don't forget the second answer by Randy6T9 who recommended
Speed Limit, apparently it works really well for localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't read that. Just tried it and it works well. I am tempted to accept your answer, could you please mention the second answer and it's link directly?

Comment: @Tobo Hopefully that tidies things up.

Answer (score 11):

Turn on developer mode and then go to [image]network tab, you will be able to see the throttling option drop-down option, change the network type from there.
See the screenshot.

Comment: wow,, but can you control more slower than GPRS,, or manual input..

Comment: Where is this option on Safari ?

Answer (score 10):

New chrome browser has "Throttling" option in "Network" tab in Dev tools.
Good Luck

Comment: "Good Luck"?! What do you mean? It works very well.

Comment: Confirmed, works well. Side note: It's been 7 years, but I think what Piyush meant with 'Good Luck' is that they guided you to the new Chrome browser feature then wished you good luck hopefully that would solve your problem, a good way. It was actually an honest, warm and sincere 'Good Luck'. However, only Piyush can truly elaborate the truth behind what they meant by saying 'Good Luck'. But even if they did, would you believe them? Only time.. will tell.

Comment: It was just warm gesture from my side. Actually I meant "Good Luck with your web project task at hand".

Answer (score 0):

I use [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), seems to do the job well.

Comment: this works well for anything but localhost it seems ...

Comment: No, should work for any host, including local loopback.

Comment: Couldn't find a way to make it slow down my local loopback, but I could map a local folder, which does the trick for me

Comment: @Tobo Often, proxy-settings by default says "do not use this proxy for localhost". Have you tried disabling this? Example picture (see the "no proxy for" setting): http://en.flossmanuals.net/bypassing-censorship/ch038_socks-proxies/_booki/bypassing-censorship/static/CircumventionTools-WhatIsAProxy-6a-en.jpg